Near Balance Mismatch for address - opp_near_disc.near
I was checking the balance for the near address: opp_near_disc.near
Explorer link: https://nearblocks.io/address/opp_near_disc.near
Its mentioned as 3.50014 N, but when I went through transaction details, after summing up it is coming as 0 only.
Could the team help me with this query? From where are we getting this much of balance?
I tried summing up all the transactions and it was expected to be 0, but the explorer shows me some balance.
